# Field for bearer access token not showing on Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui

For some reason, the input field to write the bearer access token is not showing as an implicit param on swagger UI.

This makes it impossible to access all endpoints because they require authentication.

What is showing :

[image: What's showing]

What should show :

[image: What showing]

These images are from different projects but with the same configuration classes. This is the annotation I'm using to mark the endpoints that require the bearer access token.

```
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Bearer Token", required = true,
        allowEmptyValue = false, paramType = "header", example = "Bearer access_token")
```

And lastly, this is the token configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("user")
                .secret("senha")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could help with this problem I'm having for quite a few hours. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a green "Authorize" button above the endpoint list, like in petstore.swagger.io?

Comment: i think it should be something like this `@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Bearer Token", required = true,
        allowEmptyValue = false, paramType = "header", example = "Bearer access_token") })`